# How to store textarea input into a database with hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, textarea

I made a textarea in a jsp file called information.jsp and im trying to get it to store the input from it into a database when the user clicks submit. I've made the information.hbm.xml file as shown below:

**information.jsp:**

```
<textarea id = "desc" rows="5" cols="115" onkeypress="textCounter(this,20);"><c:out value="${informationView.storedDescription}"/></textarea>
```

**information.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Information" table="INFO_USER">
      <id name="id" type="long" column="INFO_ID">
  <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">ID_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>

  <property name="description" column="DESC"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I then made a class `Information` with getters and setters for description to store and retrieve the information from the database. I just cant figure out how to get the input into description from the textarea from a submit event...

From what I've been reading I think I have to make an `InformationAction` to actually get it to save when someone clicks submit but again not sure. I'm new to Hibernate and a little lost on where I went wrong in the process of saving the input to the database and retrieving it to load into the textarea automatically if someone reopens the page.

I just can't figure out how I'm going to pass the input from the textarea to the database.
Any help would be great since I've been working on this for a long time and can't figure it out. Let me know if you need more info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need either `InformationAction` or `InformationContoller` depending on the web framework you want to use. Your action or controller needs to have a `description` property that maps to the text area value. If you use web frameworks like Struts2 or Spring MVC, this is pretty easy to achieve.

Now coming to hibernate part. Your action needs to have hibernate `Session` object that can read and write values to the database. You can then construct your `Information` object using the `description` you got from front end and then call `saveOrUpdate()` method on session.

The code would be something like this

```
public class InformationAction {
    //Maps to text area value. Needs getter and setter
    private String description;

    //Inject session from hibernate configuration
    private Session session;

    public void someMethod() {
     Information information = new Information();
     information.setDescription(description);
     session.saveOrUpdate(information);
   }
}
```

This will save a row in your Information table.